# URL being called from onclick works on desktop browsers, but not on iPad browsers

Tags: html, ipad, tableau-api

I have the following code from Tableau Public to allow users to click through to see some data in a new window:

```
<h3 onclick="location.href='https://public.tableau.com/views/CDRstats/AverageReviewSpeed?:embed=y&:showTabs=y&:display_count=yes'; target="_blank""  > Review speed </h3>
```

This works fine in any browser on a desktop/laptop, but simply does nothing on an iPad (irrespective of whether I use chrome or Safari - it just doesn't work).

Is there a simple fix that will enable this to work on an iPad?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your quotation marks are messed up.

```
<h3
    onclick="location.href='https://public.tableau.com/views/CDRstats/AverageReviewSpeed?:embed=y&:showTabs=y&:display_count=yes';"
    target="_blank">
</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am no javascript expert but I have much better results with `ontouch` which still works for desktop browsers.